# delete child entity in bidirectional OneToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have following classes in ont to one relationship.

```
DrivingLicense.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DRIVING_LICENSE")
public class DrivingLicense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "LICENSE_NUMBER")
    private int licenseNumber;
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_ISSUE")
    private Date dateOfIssue;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
}
```

and

```
Person.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private int personId;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String personName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DrivingLicense drivingLicense;
}
```

Now when I try to delete driving license entity then its not deleting it, I am confused, how to delete driving license individually?

```
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    DrivingLicense drivingLicense = entityManager.find(DrivingLicense.class, 6);
    entityManager.remove(drivingLicense);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

## Update

instead of deleting its firing below two selects

```
Hibernate: select drivinglic0_.LICENSE_NUMBER as LICENSE_NUMBER1_0_0_, drivinglic0_.DATE_OF_ISSUE as DATE_OF_ISSUE2_0_0_, drivinglic0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID3_0_0_, person1_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_1_1_, person1_.PERSON_NAME as PERSON_NAME2_1_1_ from DRIVING_LICENSE drivinglic0_ left outer join PERSON person1_ on drivinglic0_.PERSON_ID=person1_.PERSON_ID where drivinglic0_.LICENSE_NUMBER=?
Hibernate: select drivinglic0_.LICENSE_NUMBER as LICENSE_NUMBER1_0_1_, drivinglic0_.DATE_OF_ISSUE as DATE_OF_ISSUE2_0_1_, drivinglic0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID3_0_1_, person1_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_1_0_, person1_.PERSON_NAME as PERSON_NAME2_1_0_ from DRIVING_LICENSE drivinglic0_ left outer join PERSON person1_ on drivinglic0_.PERSON_ID=person1_.PERSON_ID where drivinglic0_.PERSON_ID=?
```

why these 2 selects are fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `drivingLicense` from its respective `Person` first:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

DrivingLicense drivingLicense = entityManager.find(DrivingLicense.class, 6);

Person person = drivingLicense.getPerson();
person.setDrivingLicense(null);
entityManager.merge(person);

entityManager.remove(drivingLicense);

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: yes, it worked!! can you please also add the reason why those two selects are fired?

Comment: I can only speculate, but I think the entity manager checks the cross references of the the driving license you want to delete (the person your driving license was assigned to) to prevent a break of your databases referential integrity when deleting a driving license without removing the respective foreign key column value.

Comment: I have a simple doubt in my mind about table design with this relationship, should `PERSON` table contain the `fk` of `DRIVING_LICENSE` or `DRIVING_LICENSE` should contain the `fk` of `PERSON`? what are pros and cons of both?

Comment: The answer to your question, why it fires two selects, is [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)